# Making a generic call to a wrapping class

Tags: c#, dapper

I have this static class:

```
namespace Dapper
{
    public static class SqlMapper
    {
        public static T ExecuteScalar<T>(this IDbConnection cnn, string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null)
        {
          CommandDefinition command = new CommandDefinition(sql, param, transaction, commandTimeout, commandType, CommandFlags.Buffered, new CancellationToken());
          return SqlMapper.ExecuteScalarImpl<T>(cnn, ref command);
        }

        public static Task<int> ExecuteAsync(this IDbConnection cnn, string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null)
        {
          return cnn.ExecuteAsync(new CommandDefinition(sql, param, transaction, commandTimeout, commandType, CommandFlags.Buffered, new CancellationToken()));
        }

      //...
      //Goes on for another 200 different static functions
    }
}
```

I want to create some wrapper class that will hold a default value of commandTimeout. I don't want it as a global parameter, I want this class to be build in bootstrapper with this value:

```
using Dapper;

public class SqlWrapper : ISqlWrapper
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly int _commandTimeoutInSec;

    public SqlWrapper(ILogger logger, int commandTimeoutInSec)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _commandTimeoutInSec = commandTimeoutInSec;
    }

    public async ExecuteScalarAsync<T>(IDbConnection cnn, string sql, object param = null,
         int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(cnn))
            {
                var commandGuid =
                    await conn.ExecuteScalarAsync<T>(sql, param, CommandType: CommandType, commandTimeout: commandTimeout ?? _commandTimeoutInSec);
                return commandGuid;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.WriteError(
                $"Job execute failed with error:", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public async int ExecuteAsync(IDbConnection cnn, string sql, object param = null, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(cnn))
            {
                var commandGuid =
                    await
                        conn.ExecuteAsync(sql, param, CommandType: CommandType,
                            commandTimeout: commandTimeout ?? _commandTimeoutInSec);
                return commandGuid;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.WriteError(
                $"Job execute failed with error:", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    //...
    //Goes on for the rest 200 different static functions in SqlMapper
}
```

the thing is, I feel like it's stupid to implement a wrapper for 200 functions to to pass a default parameter, is there a way to receive the name of the function as a template of  parameter and then pass on the call to the same name in SqlMapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may apply the following technique to your scenario. Imagine we had this static class:

```
public static class Printer
{
    public static void Print(string output, int numberOfTimes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }

    public static void Show(string output, int numberOfTimes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
}
```

And let's imagine we wanted to give the `numberOfTimes` a default value, then we can do this:

```
public class DefaultPrinter
{
    private int defaultTimes = 10;
    public void ExecuteMethod(Action<string, int> action, string output)
    {
        action(output, defaultTimes);
    }
}
```

Now the users will not have to indicate how many times the print should occur because the above class will do it for a default of 10 times.

**Usage**

```
var printer = new DefaultPrinter();
printer.ExecuteMethod((a, b) => Printer.Print(a, b), "One");
printer.ExecuteMethod((a, b) => Printer.Show(a, b), "Two");
```

Comment: But what about the return value? and the template <T>?

Comment: I thought you'd be able to figure that out.